# c++ constructors and concurrency

Tags: c++, concurrency, constructor

I've been thinking about writing a container class to control access to a complex data structure that will have use in a multi-threaded environment.

And then the question occurred to me:

Is there ever a situation where c++ constructors must be thread-safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in my experience. It is the code that *calls* the constructor, implicitly or otherwise, which needs to be made thread-safe should the application require it.

The rationale is that only one thread should be initializing an object at a time, so no synchronization is necessary to protect the object being initialized within the constructor itself (if the object hasn't finished initialization, it shouldn't be shared between threads anyway).

Another way to look at it is this: Objects are to be treated as logically nonexistent until their constructors have returned. So, a thread that is in the process of creating an object is the only thread that "knows" about it.

Of course, proper synchronization rules apply to any shared resource the constructor *itself* accesses, but that applies to any function (I've encountered people that fail to realize this, believing constructors are special and somehow provide exclusive access to all resources).

Comment: This is not entirely true. There are thread-safe concerns for the constructor when you use singleton design pattern. And right now I'm searching a workaround for this situation.

Answer (score 5):

In general, a constructor cannot be called for the *same* object by two threads simultaneously. However, the same constructor can certainly be called for *different* objects at the same time.

Comment: Not true for singleton patterns.

Comment: @PDuarte with a singleton, there's still just one constructor called once.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly you can invoke the same constructor from more than one thread at once.  It that sense, they must be thread-safe, just as any other function must be.  If the constructor is going to modify shared state, for example, your container, then you must use synchronization to ensure that the state is modified in a deterministic way.

You can't construct the same object on more than one thread at once, because each object is only constructed once, so there's no way to invoke the constructor on the same object more than once, much less on two different threads at the same time.

Comment: In c++ the object does technically exist until the constructor completes, so if the contructor doesn't have side effects outside the object, can other threads access it?

Comment: But there are ways that you might end up trying to construct two different objects in the same space at the same time... placement new comes to mind. While you may not be doing this yourself. This could also happen if you're pushing back entries into a vector. This can't happen if you have synchronization protecting the memory location of the objects to be created though - in this example a lock on the vector.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson, I'm not following your vector example.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Two threads access the same vector at the same time, and both simultaneously call `push_back`.